# How to achieve Delay in State Machine Workflow

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, workflowservice

Windows Workflow State Machine
has a state (`AwaitingFeedbackState`) with two transitions.

Transition 1) awaiting receive message from client within "Trigger" body, email activity within "Action"

Transition 2) `CheckReminderEnabledActivity` within "Trigger" body, delay and email reminder activity within "Action"

when `CheckReminderEnabledActivity` is true, the behaviour works fine, the work flow goes into delay but if it is 
set to false, the workflow infinity loops in `AwaitingFeedbackState`, keeps hitting `CheckReminderEnabledActivity`.

Is there a way to disable this transition if `CheckReminderEnabledActivity` is set to false when process enters `CheckReminderEnabledActivity` for 
the first time ?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by bringing in the delay and send reminder activity within the trigger body and have now also added if else as well. In the else body I have added a custom bookmark as per example here 
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Workflow-50c3fba5